# How to add extra resources with electron-forge

Tags: electron, electron-forge

I'm using `electron-forge` and want to add extra resources to the executable. The problem is that when I specify the extra resources, it adds my entire top-level repository (including folders/files that are ignored with .gitignore) AND the extra resource that I want. How can I *only* include the extra resource I'm interested in, or is this normal behavior?

When I add `extraResource` as shown below, it adds two additional folders. One is called `app` and the other is `resources`. `resources` is what I want. `app` contains the entire local repository, which I do not want.

I have confirmed this is happening by logging `process.resourcesPath`.

**forge.config.ts**

```
import type { ForgeConfig } from '@electron-forge/shared-types';
import { MakerSquirrel } from '@electron-forge/maker-squirrel';
import { MakerZIP } from '@electron-forge/maker-zip';
import { MakerDeb } from '@electron-forge/maker-deb';
import { MakerRpm } from '@electron-forge/maker-rpm';
import { VitePlugin } from '@electron-forge/plugin-vite';

const config: ForgeConfig = {
  packagerConfig: {
    extraResource: ['./resources'],
  },
  rebuildConfig: {},
  makers: [
    new MakerSquirrel({}),
    new MakerZIP({}, ['darwin']),
    new MakerRpm({}),
    new MakerDeb({}),
  ],
  plugins: [
    new VitePlugin({
      // `build` can specify multiple entry builds, which can be Main process, Preload scripts, Worker process, etc.
      // If you are familiar with Vite configuration, it will look really familiar.
      build: [
        {
          // `entry` is just an alias for `build.lib.entry` in the corresponding file of `config`.
          entry: 'src/main.ts',
          config: 'vite.main.config.ts',
        },
        {
          entry: 'src/preload.ts',
          config: 'vite.preload.config.ts',
        },
      ],
      renderer: [
        {
          name: 'main_window',
          config: 'vite.renderer.config.ts',
        },
      ],
    }),
  ],
};

export default config;
```